# MSSQL Express Logfile ist too big

Tags: sql-server, windows-sbs-2008

Its on a SBS2008 Server, and we're running out of space. when checking what's the reason i found that the Errorlog from MSSQ is using above 50 gigs (see Picture)

[image]

How can i solve this? google doens't show me the right solution..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run [sp_cycle_errorlog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182512.aspx). Schedule that to happen semi-frequently (once a week maybe?).

Comment: Running 'Exec Sp_Cycle_Errorlog' severall times solved the problem for now.

Comment: @MemLeak: I was thinking more of a SQL Agent job, but whatever stirs your chili.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer Configure the sql server error logs to keep less log files (management folder) - more details to follow